# Cannot find module './accelerometer'

Tags: johnny-five, tessel

I'm getting the below error when trying to run johnny-five on my tessel 2:

```
Error: Cannot find module './accelerometer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/remote-script/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/johnny-five.js:1:152)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I've tried installing the module but the error still appears.

Any pointers please would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Node version 8.11.1.
It worked for me. Took two days to figure it out.

If it doesn't work, check the version the package.json is on tessel-io and johnny-five. If the node version in the package.json is different from the node version you're using, update it or downgrade it to that package.json node version.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and now get:   ERR! Node version mismatch for USB drivers.
INFO To correct this issue, please run the following command:
INFO 
INFO   npm rebuild --update-binary usb.

Comment: Running: npm rebuild --update-binary usb doesn't fix the issue above for me.

Comment: I don't know why, but going back to node v9.9.0 after trying the above made it work. Any ideas why? @FluffyMocha - thank you for your help.